# Input file path with dates ADFV2

Tags: u-sql, azure-data-factory

Currently we are moving out data analytics pipeline to ADFV2. In V1 we defined the input filepath in the parameter file as - `/Inputpath/{filedate:yyyy}.{filedate:MM}.{filedate:dd}/RealtimeUsage.{filedate:yyyy}.{filedate:MM}.{filedate:dd}.{filedate:HH}.{*}csv`

How is this accomplished in ADFV2. The activity reads in the parameter from the parameter file as such -

```
"ActivityName": {
"path": "$.properties.activities[?(@.name=='ActivityName')].typeProperties.ParameterName",
          "value": "/Input/{filedate:yyyy}.{filedate:MM}.{filedate:dd}/RealtimeUsage.{filedate:yyyy}.{filedate:MM}.{filedate:dd}.{filedate:HH}.{*}csv"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read a file in the following pattern:
Inputpath/2018.07.26/RealtimeUsage.2018.07.26.01.{*}csv

You could write your file path expression in the following:

```js
"fileName": {
type: "Expression",
value: "RealtimeUsage.@{formatDateTime(pipeline().parameters.windowStart,'yyyy')}.@{formatDateTime(pipeline().parameters.windowStart,'MM')}.@{formatDateTime(pipeline().parameters.windowStart,'dd')}.@{formatDateTime(pipeline().parameters.windowStart,'HH')}.{*}csv",
}
```

You could also use the [copy data tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-copy-data-tool) to help you generate this expression.
[image]

Comment: One thing to note: you have to copy/paste the "Example" into "File or folder" so that the UI will expose the date / time drop-downs. Until you copy / paste though, the initial UI you see from the wizard appears to have fewer options that the example above. I will say though, that following this wizard all the way through, and reviewing what it generates (sources, sinks, triggers, etc.) is really helpful for understanding how to parameterize ADFv2.